# Load balancing and stateful session in Coldfusion 5

Tags: coldfusion, load-balancing, stateful

Does ColdFusion 5 supports load balancing and stateful sessions?

If there is a stateful session,how to find the type like sticky session, persistent storage,etc?

Comment: No idea, but you could probably find out by checking the documentation :). The docs for older versions are still available for download here [ColdFusion 5.0 Documentation](https://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/coldfusion/documentation50.html).

Comment: Session aware Load Balancing is supported using ClusterCATS - https://www.manualslib.com/manual/389780/Macromedia-Coldfusion-5-Advanced-Administration.html?page=294